# Are the limits $\lim_{m_1 \to \infty} v_1 \sqrt{\frac{m_1m_2}{(m_1+m_2)k}}$ and $\lim_{m_2 \to 0} v_1 \sqrt{\frac{m_1m_2}{(m_1+m_2)k}}$ equivalent?

Tags: limits

Given the following expression

$$v_1 \sqrt{\frac{m_1m_2}{(m_1+m_2)k}}$$

I'd like to know what the limit is when $m_1$ becomes infinitely large relative to $m_2$. I think this means the same as saying "when $m_2$ becomes infinitely small relative to $m_1$.

Do the following two limits give the same result?

$$\lim_{m_1 \to \infty} v_1 \sqrt{\frac{m_1m_2}{(m_1+m_2)k}}\tag{1}$$

$$\lim_{m_2 \to 0} v_1 \sqrt{\frac{m_1m_2}{(m_1+m_2)k}}\tag{2}$$

It seems to me that $(1)$ is $v_1\sqrt{\frac{m_2}{k}}$ and $(2)$ is $0$. Is this correct?

We can rewrite the expression as

$$v_1 \sqrt{\frac{m_1}{m_1+m_2}}\sqrt{\frac{m_2}{k}}$$

When $m_1$ approaches infinity, the middle root approaches 1.
When $m_2$ approaches zero, the last root approaches 0.

Is there something wrong with these calculations?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: "when $m_1$ becomes infinitely large relative to $m_2$" This would be the limit of the function when $m_1/m_2 \to \infty$ (which is equal to the limit when $m_2/m_1 \to 0^+$)

Answer (score 1):

Try breaking them up, it is easier to tell:
$$\lim_{m_1\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{m_1m_2}{(m_1+m_2)k}}=\lim_{m_1\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{m_2}k}\sqrt{\frac{m_1}{m_1+m_2}}=\sqrt{\frac{m_2}{k}}$$
since the $m_2$ becomes negligible in the second square root.

For the second limit, under the assumption that $m_1\ne0$ it is equally easy to evaluate noticing that the top of the fraction goes to zero whilst the bottom does not. Another way you could evaluate limits like this is just by rewriting and see if it helps you to visualise whats going on:
$$\frac{m_1m_2}{m_1+m_2}=\cfrac{m_1}{\cfrac{m_1}{m_2}+1}$$
now look at what happens if, say, $m_1\to0$